# OpenAPI: how to validate examples?

Tags: validation, jsonschema, openapi

RAML automatically validates included examples with the corresponding schema when you render the documentation.

Is there a way to do the same with an OpenAPI 3 spec?

[codekie/swagger-examples-validator](https://github.com/codekie/swagger-examples-validator) currently only supports OpenAPI 2.

Anyone knows an easy solution to check all the examples against their schemas?

Comment: Doesn't SwaggerEditor do that for you?

Comment: @MCMatan at least the free version does not seem to check the examples. But codekie/swagger-examples-validator now partially supports OpenAPI 3 - `examples` properties are checked but singular `example` properties seem not to be recognized with the current version

Comment: codekie/openapi-examples-validator (formerly known as swagger-examples-validator) supports the singular `example`-property by now.

Comment: I am not able to validate any example... codekie/openapi-examples-validator always returns: "Validating examples
Schemas with examples found: 0
Examples without schema found: 0
Total examples found: 0

No errors found."

Answer (score 3):

The official OpenAPI-tools don't validate referenced examples, especially because the official spec doesn't even require the example to match the schema (see: [OpenAPI specification](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#fixed-fields-11)), it only states that it "should" match:

> Examples of the media type. Each example object SHOULD match the media
> type and specified schema if present.

You will have to rely on third party tools.

One option would be [codekie/openapi-examples-validator](https://github.com/codekie/openapi-examples-validator), which supports the OpenAPI 3 spec by now